# class not foundを解決したい

Tags: php, fuelphp

fuelphpでDBにインサートをする処理をしているのですが、
Class 'Controller' not foundになります。
name spaceをつけていないからでしょうか。
お手数おかけしますがご回答頂けると幸いです。

エラーコード(このページは動作していません
localhost では現在このリクエストを処理できません。
HTTP ERROR 500)

```
[06-Aug-2018 04:40:09 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Controller' not found in /Users/■■■■/Desktop/fuelphp/fuel/app/classes/controller/friend2.php on line 3
```

friend2.php(/Users/■■■■/Desktop/fuelphp/fuel/app/classes/controller)

```
<?php

class Controller_Friend2 extends Controller {

    public function action_insert() {

    DB::insert('friend')->set(array(
        'id' => '777',
        'name' => '梅宮達夫',
        'age' => '71',
        'sex' => '男',
    ))->execute();
         }
}
?>
```

db.php(/Users/■■■■/Desktop/fuelphp/fuel/app/config)

```
<?php
return array(
    'default' => array(
        'type'        => 'mysqli',
        'connection'  => array(
            'persistent' => false,
        ),
        'identifier'   => '`',
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'charset'      => 'utf8',
        'collation'    => false,
        'enable_cache' => true,
        'profiling'    => false,
        'readonly'     => false,
    ),
);
```

db.php(/Users/■■■■/Desktop/fuelphp/fuel/app/config/development)

```
<?php
return array(
  'default' => array(
    'connection'  => array(
        'dsn'    => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=personal',
        'port'     => '3306',
        'username'   => 'root',
        'password'   => 'root',
       ),
        'profiling' => true,
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

friend2.phpファイルの先頭あたりで、require_once等でControllerクラスが定義されているphpファイルを指定してみてください。

require_onceの詳細については以下を参照してください。
http://php.net/manual/ja/function.require-once.php